# PHP - regular expression (preg_match)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

```
<?php
$string = "http://example.com/file/D1 http://example.com/file/D2
http://example.com/file/D3";
preg_match_all('/(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.com\/file\/(\w+)/i', $string, $matches);  
foreach($matches[3] as $value)
{  
print $value;  
}
?>
```

I want to preg match the third link and get "D3". 
I dont want that it matches with the other two links. This is why it should check if the link has a whitespace at the beginning or the end.
I know that to match with whitespace the expression is `\s`. I tried but somehow I don't get it. :(

Comment: Do you really need regex? it will be easier by using string manipulation.

Comment: Yes I really need regex.

Comment: Do you really need `preg_match_all`? And what is the criteria for the D3 link? Is it always the third link? Is it always at the end of the string?

Comment: Yes I really need `preg_match_all`. There is now criteria for the D3 Link except that It does not have whitespace before or after. No, it is not always the third link and it is not always at the end. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `$` to match the end of the string like this, and it will only return the last one.

```
preg_match_all('/(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.com\/file\/(\w+)$/i', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: This just displays the last one.
But the link doesn't have to be the last one.